# deleting the previous records in leads and creating new records using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

i need to create a record but before creating thr record i neeed to delete all the old records that is having status closed converted...my code is

```
trigger deleteRecords on Lead (after insert){
List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
List<Lead> ld = [select id from Lead where status = 'closed-converted'];
for(Lead oLead : trigger.new){
    system.debug('inside for:'+ld);
    Account oAccount = new Account();
    oAccount.Name = oLead.FirstName;
    acc.add(oAccount);
}
if(acc.size()>0){
    insert acc;
}
if(ld.size()>0){
    delete ld;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry whats the real issue here in tigger?

Comment: actually i need to create a new record in lead ,when it s created all the old records in my lead that is having status closed converted should be deleted ....i dont get any errors in my code ...but still the old records are not being deleted

Comment: Are there any records in ld? give a system.debug to check it.

Comment: ya there are many records...

Comment: thats strange... is it executing the delete statement? scan the debug log for any exception. if it is executing the delete statement then it should delete them or atleast throw an exception. Do you have a try catch block for delete

Comment: delete statement is not working

Comment: can anyone help me by editing this code ...my delete statement not working

Comment: i got out put ...actually what went wrong was the spacing in the status field.

Answer (score 1):

I got the out put....actually the spacing in the status field 'closed-converted' is wrong in the above code .After changing that im getting out put....Bingo..

Comment: As Prady suggested 'Are there any records in ld? give a system.debug to check it.'